# What I have to return here for created

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

```
protected NoContentResult SuccessWithOutData()
{
    return this.NoContent();
}

protected CreatedAtActionResult SuccessAndNoData()
{
    return ? ; // What do I return here?
}
```

For 201 result what do I have to return here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I code a Created-201 response using IHttpActionResult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23892341/how-can-i-code-a-created-201-response-using-ihttpactionresult)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return Ok(string);
```

is what I use

Comment: i think ok for 200 but i need 201

Comment: try return `StatusCode(201);`  or `return Created();`

Answer (score 0):

You could check the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerBase class and you would find all the methods to retrun  response

[image]

[image]

And you could check this document to learn the difference between  responses:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/actions?view=aspnetcore-6.0#controller-helper-methods